# Are we able to connect linq to sql sever connectivity in Ionic framework? If we can then how we do this?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, linq-to-sql

I am starter developer in Ionic framework, I have sql server database which one previously using `linq` to `sqlserver` as connectivity with asp.net. now I want to know ,Is it possible to connect database with `linq` in `ionic` framework ?
  Currently I am using visual studio 2013 and angular js in ionic. We are able create dbml data classes

```
DBcontext = new DataClassesDataContext(connectionString);
```

but after i am stuck in mapping. Please if any body have any information then share with me.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

No, there's no workaround, no magic involved, it's just not the way this is supposed to work. Ionic works on top of Angular and Angular is a frontend framework.

However, the way you should do it is that you basically create a (RESTful) API on your server side.

After you write your (RESTful) API then you can consume it through your services in Angular by using Angular's $resource (or $http) service.

Sure, this is not a step by step answer, and it seems you're just starting in this area, so you have some learning to do on your part (REST, RESTful, $resource, services...), but I wish you good luck and if you'll have any more specific questions, don't hesitate to ask them.